# Setting <li> class as active using Javascript, not working?

Tags: javascript, css

I have several javascript generated sub menus, which are displayed when a certain word is found in the current url.

I need to set a `li` tag to `li class="active"` so that the user can see which submenu page they are currently browsing.

I've found a variety of codes which seem to be relevant, but I can't seem to make any work! The below works perfectly to generate the sub menus though :)

If it helps I'm using the twitter bootsrap for design purposes, for some reason the css file has alot of arrows inserted, eg. `.tabs > li`

I don't really understand what the `>` has been inserted for, but could that be causing some kind of a problem perhaps?

Any help much appreciated!

```
var currenturl = location.pathname

if (currenturl.search(/welcome/i) >= 0)
    {
    document.write(<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="welcome.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact_us.php">Contacts</a></li>
    <li><a href="user_manual.php" User Manual</a></li>
    <li><a href="help.php">Support &amp; Help</a></li>
    <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>);
    }
```

Ok Here's an update!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Wow thanks very much for the reply. I have added the code inside a javascript declaration before the closing body tag as mentioned, though on the welcome.php page I do not see any sub menu having been generated.

In response to the other comment, what I would like to achieve is generating a sub menu based upon the current pages URL.

If the URL contains "support" I would like it to load a certain menu, if "sales" I would like it to load another.

An example sub menu, the one I want to appear when "sales" is detected in the URL is as follows:

```
<ul class="tabs"> 
<li><a href="sales-contact_us.php">Contacts</a></li> 
<li><a href="sales-user_manual.php" User Manual</a></li> 
<li><a href="sales-help.php">Support &amp; Help</a></li> 
<li><a href="sales-something.php">Something Else</a></li> 
</ul>
```

To make the current sub menu active I have to further set an li tag active as such:

```
<li class="active">
```

This means I will need another piece of code to detect the end of the URL string eg. if the current page open is sales-contact_us.php then the li tag for that menu item is set active.

Thanks!

Comment: `document.write` is **not** the way to add elements to the document. Use [DOM methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference) instead. The `>` in your CSS is the [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors)

Comment: Can you give us a more specific question than "I can't seem to make any work!"?

Comment: Hi Jordan, hope that helps, any help much appreciated!

Comment: I would avoid using javascript to generate your navigation for SEO reasons. Search engine crawlers will not be able to crawl your site as they don't execute script. You will need to use a sitemap or similar if you generate your nav using javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely not use `document.write` to append elements to the document. Use DOM methods instead, eg

```
var menu = [
    { "label": "Home", "href": "welcome.php" },
    { "label": "Contacts", "href": "contact_us.php" }
    // etc
];

var list = document.createElement("ul");
list.setAttribute("class", "tabs");
for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
    var label = menu[i].label;
    var href = menu[i].href;

    var item = document.createElement("li");
    var anchor = document.createElement("a");
    anchor.appendChild(document.createTextNode(label));
    anchor.setAttribute("href", href);
    if (href == currentUrl) {
        item.setAttribute("class", "active");
    }
    item.appendChild(anchor);
    list.appendChild(item);
}

document.body.appendChild(list); // you may want to append the list to another container
```

Place the above in a script block at the end of your document (right before the closing `</body>` tag) to ensure the document has loaded before attempting to manipulate it.

Comment: Phil could you offer any more explanation based on what I have added in the question please? After reading about DOM, this seems great but it's not quite working! Many thanks!